# Combine SQL Count Results

Tags: sql

I'm currently trying to teach myself SQL in order to write better reports with our Orion system and I'm running into a small issue. I want to generate a report with a count of the number of Windows machines and Linux machines. This is my current code.

```
   SELECT OperatingSystem, Count(OperatingSystem) AS TotalMachines
    FROM Machines
    Where
    (
    (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%') OR 
    (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%')
    )
    GROUP BY OperatingSystem
```

And the return I get is this

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux            20
Novell SUSE Linux Enterprise        17
Debian Linux                         5
Windows Server 2008 (32-bit)        11
Windows Server 2008 R2 (32-bit)     49
Windows Server 2008 (64-bit)        33
Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bits)    16
Windows Server 2003 (32-bit)        35
```

Is it possible to combine all of the different Linux Operating Systems into a single row called Linux and combine all of the Windows Operating Systems into a single row called Windows in an SQL Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve such problems I prefer to use `union` neither `case`, as it helps you easily extend query in future:

```
select OSType, count(*) as TotalMachines
from (
    SELECT 'Linux' as OSType FROM Machines WHERE OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Windows' as OSType FROM Machines WHERE OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%'
) as subquery
GROUP BY OSType
```

in any case, check both variants and select fastest

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You want to use `case` in the `group by` clause itself:

```
SELECT (case when OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%' then 'Windows'
            when OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%' then 'Linux'
       end) as WhichOs, Count(*) AS TotalMachines
FROM Machines
Where (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%') OR 
      (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%')
GROUP BY (case when OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%' then 'Windows'
               when OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%' then 'Linux
          end);
```

EDIT:

The above should work (note the same expression is in the `select` and `group by`.  Perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT WhichOs, Count(*) AS TotalMachines
FROM (SELECT m.*,
            (case when OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%' then 'Windows'
                  when OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%' then 'Linux'
             end) as WhichOs
      FROM Machines m
     ) m
Where (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%') OR 
      (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%')
GROUP BY WhichOs;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!I ran this and it returned the error Column Machines.OperatingSystem is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Then I tried just adding OperatingSystem, before the CASE in the group by and it worked, but the return gives me a section for Linux with the values 20, 17, and 5 listed in serperate rows and the same for windows. I would like to add them all together in order to have a row that Says "Linux    42" is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  case 
    when OperatingSystem like '%Windows%' then 'Windows'
    when OperatingSystem like '%Linux%' then 'Linux'
    else 'Other'
 end as Operating_System
, Count(OperatingSystem) AS TotalMachines
FROM Machines
Where
(
   (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Windows%') OR 
   (OperatingSystem LIKE '%Linux%')
)
GROUP BY 
  OperatingSystem
, case 
    when OperatingSystem like '%Windows%' then 'Windows'
    when OperatingSystem like '%Linux%' then 'Linux'
    else 'Other'
end
```